# Visual Studio 2008 Productivity Power Tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, productivity-power-tools

I see these have been released for VS 2010.  I am trying to locate them for VS 2008, but I am not able to find them.  Can anyone provide a link?  Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure they exist?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't believe that the [Productivity Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx) exist for Visual Studio 2008 ([see here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) where it only shows that 2010 is supported); they were exclusively released for Visual Studio 2010.

However, the Power Commands were released for both Visual Studio 2008 ([see here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands)) and Visual Studio 2010 ([see here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99)).

Comment: Well I guess that is why I can't find them!  From the 2010 Tools post I thought it indicated 2008 had a version for that as well.  It was probably talking about a prior release for 2010.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @John: You're welcome. It would be nice if some of those tools were in 2008.

Comment: Does anyone have this still on your computer? All the websites are pointing to the archive, but it isn't there anymore. Also get bounty here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759073

Comment: @Highmastdon: I might have it on a backup somewhere. I try to make time to look tomorrow, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: @JeffYates I've found one. You can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26730210/431967

Comment: @Highmastdon: Excellent!