# Where can I find PowerCommands for VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, powercommands

I am using VS2008 at work with no plans to upgrade in the near future.  I sorely miss the features of PowerCommands that I have for VS2010+.

**[Here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3f0c30-3d37-4e06-9ef8-3bff3508be31)** is the gallery but it references the archive.

All of the old links point me to http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands which has been retired.  I couldn't convince archive.org to cough it up either.

Does anyone have a link to this addin anywhere?

Alternately, if anyone has some replacements I'd be just as happy.

The functions I miss most:

- Collapse Projects
- Copy/Paste References
- Insert Guid

Comment: For some reason one answer has been removed. Here is a screenshot for further reference: http://i.imgur.com/eW21Smy.png Softopedia url: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/PowerCommands.shtml

Comment: PowerCommands was a sample project (http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/04/17/LearnVSXNowPart19.aspx). I believe you can find the source here: https://code.google.com/p/huiqiu/source/browse/trunk/+huiqiu+--username+iceeer/project/?r=72#project%2FPowerCommands

Comment: In case the link in the accepted answer ever goes away (because it will). The SHA256 hash of the MSI file that I installed is 573CD5D154D3049EDF64597B5E2E52C4DC45EA018337DB81B5AD343C3B7C4D35

Comment: You can also get a hold of it here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1d72d2f7a8295a3407ea47fb54611ad1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contacting Microsoft did the trick for me. At https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=38EB61838A7224E1%21107, you can find what you need :) Besides the Visual Studio 2008 PowerCommands, you can find a bunch of other tools, fixes and packs over there.

Comment: @Obsidian how doesn't this provide an answer to the question? The questions states clearly: "Does anyone have a link to this addin anywhere?" Also the bounty is worthy I think: "The bounty winner should at least provide the requested Power Commands for Visual Studio 2008".

Comment: Fair enough, I retract my statement.

Comment: @Highmastdon Well the problem is, that the whole question is off-topic, as it asks for an off-site resource. The other problem is that answers to such questions can be only links, and link-only answers are considered a bad practice.

Comment: That's correct. But for the reason that you can't use attachments here, you can only use links to ask for such thing. But that brings back the fact that the question might be indeed off-topic

Comment: Chrome has blocked this downloads, as It states the content is malicious.

Comment: My Chrome hasn't.  ("Version 46.0.2490.80 m  Google Chrome is up to date.")

Answer (score 0):

Here's another thing I've found: [CoolCommands](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2007/12/12/coolcommands-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx), also described [here](http://salvoz.com/blog/2008/01/14/cool-commands/). This add-in is PowerCommand's predecessor and, by the description, it includes:

> Collapsing all projects in the solution explorer
>
> Opening a Command Prompt at a location
>
> Opening the project’s folder
>
> Switching to a demo font
>
> Using your mouse wheel to zoom
>
> Sending code selections via e-mail

and copying references.

There is an important information on how to install them on VS2008. The "install.bat* file needs to be modified, to register within the correct VS version:

```
regpkg CoolCommands.dll /root:Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0 /codebase
```

or for VS2008 SP1:

```
regpkg CoolCommands.dll /root:Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 /codebase
```

(depending on your VS path).

Comment: I'm not able to add these to Visual Studio 2008. Tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653436/how-to-visual-studio-add-in-manager.  This is the tool from Reflector (http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/REF8/Using+the+.NET+Reflector+Power+Commands). So It's not the version I'm looking for.

Comment: @Highmastdon OK, sorry to hear that. I've found nothing more unfortunately.

Comment: @Highmastdon I've found a package that seems to match most of requirements in the question. Please let me now if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, this might serve as an alternative, though the other answer provides the tools in question.